# FileReader readAsDataURL() method not read large pdf file 24 MB in typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

```
let fileReader = new FileReader();
 fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

readAsDataURL method reading smaller files( below 5mb) file and upload also working fine.But when I upload larger file( 24MB) it is not reading them, filereader.result getting null in IE browser.In Chrome it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). It is more efficient to stream the `file` object directly.

```
var config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined } };

$http.post(url, file, config)
  .then(function (response) {
    var data = response.data;
    var status = response.status;
    var statusText = response.statusText;
    var headers = response.headers;
    var config = response.config;

    console.log("Success");
    return response; 
}).catch(function (errorResponse)
    console.log("Error");
    throw errorResponse;
});
```

The [XHR Send Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) knows how to stream `file` objects as they are just a special type of [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob). This avoids the overhead of bringing all of the file into memory.

It as important to set the content type header to `undefined` so that the [XHR send method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) can set the content type header. Otherwise the AngularJS framework will override with content type `application/json`.

For more information, see [AngularJS $http Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).