# How to upload multiple files in angular js and convert it into base 64

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

I am used single file upload and convert it to base 64 which was working fine.I am trying to upload multiple files and convert each file to base 64 in which i have used the following directive.What happens is all the image is converted into a single base 64
I would like to convert each image file to base 64.so that can anyone help me how to achieve it.

Directive:

```
"use strict";
(function() {
angular.module("SS.pages").directive("fileModel", fileModel);

/** @ngInject */
function fileModel($parse, $q) {
 return {
  restrict: "A",
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel),
      modelSetter = model.assign;
    element.bind("change", function() {
      var files = [];
      angular.forEach(element[0].files,function(file) {
        files.push(file);
      });
      scope.$apply(function() {
        // var file = element[0].files[0];
        angular.forEach(files, function(file) {
          getFileBuffer(file).then(function(resp) {
            modelSetter(scope, resp);
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
};
function getFileBuffer(file) {
  var deferred = new $q.defer();
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function(e) {
    deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
  };
  reader.onerror = function(e) {
    deferred.reject(e.target.error);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  return deferred.promise;
}
}

})();
```

Html:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label translate>.NEW.UPLOAD</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="schemeupload" accept="image/jpeg,application/jpeg" file-model="vm.schemeApply.document" multiple/>
      <p class="help-block" translate>.NEW.UPLOADMESSAGE</p>
      <span class="help-block error-block basic-block" translate>.NEW.REQUIRED</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: It would be wiser to upload the files directly. Converting them to base64 adds 33% extra overhead.

Answer (score 0):

It would be wiser to upload the files directly. Converting them to base64 adds 33% extra overhead

```
app.directive("filesInput", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function postLink(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel) {
      elem.on("change", function(e) {
        var files = elem[0].files;
        ngModel.$setViewValue(files);
      })
    }
  }
});
```

## Usage

```
<input type="file" files-input ng-model="filesArray" 
       ng-change="uploadMultiple(filesArray)" multiple />
```

JS

```
$scope.uploadMultiple = function(filesArray) {
     var config = { headers: {'Content-Type': undefined} };
     var promises = filesArray.map(function (file) {
         return $http.post(url, file, config);
     });
     $q.all(promises)
       .then(function(responseArray) {
         console.log("All files uploaded");
     }).catch(function(error) {
         console.log("ERROR", error);
     });
};
```

Converting large files to base64 has been known to cause problems. See, [FileReader readAsDataURL() method not read large pdf file 24 MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42689377/filereader-readasdataurl-method-not-read-large-pdf-file-24-mb-in-typescript/42690302#42690302).